# OpenLayers: cannot register custom projections

Tags: openlayers

I'm trying to load an OpenLayers map with UTM projection. If I try to register custom projection, the map becomes blank.

```
proj4.defs('EPSG:32640', '+proj=utm +zone=40 +datum=WGS84 +units=m +no_defs');

let options = {};
options.code = 'EPSG:32640';
options.units = 'm';


options.extent = [
  -98570.85212537996,
  2468701.5790765425,
  683268.1076887846,
  2874585.9453238174,
];

options.worldExtent = [];

options.axisOrientation = 'enu';

options.global = false;


//options.metersPerUnit = projectionOptions.metersPerUnit;
options.getPointResolution = ()=>{};

let projection = new ol.proj.Projection(options);
//ol.proj.addProjection(projection); // if I uncomment this the map becomes blank
//let ext=ol.proj.get('EPSG:32640').getExtent();
debugger;
//let center= ol.extent.getCenter(ext);
var olview = new ol.View({
  center: [312234.8270497762, 2636116.2213047906],
  extent:options.extent,
  projection: 'EPSG:32640',
  zoom: 8,
});
var map = new ol.Map({
  layers: [
    new ol.layer.Tile({
      source: new ol.source.OSM(),
    }),
  ],
  target: 'map',
  view: olview,
});
```

[Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/wfheTcVKcXHZZ0R5FaYJ?p=preview)

```
ol.proj.addProjection(projection); // if I uncomment this line, map becomes blank
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to set `extent` also on projection:

```
proj4.defs('EPSG:32640', '+proj=utm +zone=40 +datum=WGS84 +units=m +no_defs');

extent = [
  -98570.85212537996,
  2468701.5790765425,
  683268.1076887846,
  2874585.9453238174
];

ol.proj.get('EPSG:32640').setExtent(extent);

var olview = new ol.View({
  center: [312234.8270497762, 2636116.2213047906],
  extent: extent,
  projection: 'EPSG:32640',
  zoom: 0,
});

var map = new ol.Map({
  layers: [
    new ol.layer.Tile({
      source: new ol.source.OSM(),
    }),
  ],
  target: 'map',
  view: olview,
});
```

Answer (score 0):

When the projection definition is available from proj4 it's no longer a custom projection, you can simply get it from proj4 and set its extent

replace

```
let projection = new ol.proj.Projection(options);
ol.proj.addProjection(projection);
```

with

```
let projection = ol.proj.get(options.code);
projection.setExtent(options.extent);
```

Are your coordinates correct?  This is what I get[image]

Here's part of a larger UTM 40 projection map displaying a zone 40 graticule.  I've drawn an appropriate box formed by your coordinates on the screenshot.  The previous result is what I would expect with those values.[image]

Comment: still no luck , my map still showing a different extent than expected